# Проблема с запросом Mysql

Tags: mysql

Есть запрос

```
SELECT `items`.* 
FROM `items` 
LEFT JOIN `item_prop` 
       ON `item_prop`.`item_id` = `items`.`id` 
WHERE ((row_id=1) AND (value=1)) 
  AND ((row_id=6) AND (value>147811) AND (value<1000000)) 
ORDER BY `id` DESC 
LIMIT 8
```

Как его можно изменить, что бы он фильтрировал по 2-м параметрам? сейчас есть позиции которые попадают под 2 условия, но они не выводятся. В чем ошибка?

Comment: Заменить AND на OR между группами скобок. потому что у одной записи не может быть одновременно row_id=1 И row_id=6. Поэтому нам и надо row_id=1 ИЛИ row_id=6

Comment: Вот это все `((row_id=1) AND (value=1)) AND ((row_id=6) AND (value>147811) AND (value<1000000))` зачем в кавычках?  Все ровно оно сработает когда все условия будут верны

Comment: Посмотрите логические операции тут. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F

Comment: проблема в том, что мне как раз надо, что бы фильтрировало по 2-м параметрам - https://yadi.sk/d/nxlka2ZP3KVaxB

Comment: то есть, что бы оно видело, что есть `row_id=1` и `value=1`, и `row_id=5` и `value=0`

Comment: @Diefair Тогда Akina правильно указал дубль и вам надо поставить OR и применить GROUP BY с подсчетом подошедших строк

Comment: нет, потому что мне надо что бы и то и то было, а не то или то

Comment: @Diefair предлагаю вам вспомнить школьный курс логики и правила де Моргана, согласно которым AND легко превращается в OR через двойное отрицание

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT /* DISTINCT */ i.* 
FROM items i
JOIN item_prop ip1
  ON ip1.item_id = i.id AND ip1.row_id=1 AND ip1value=1 
JOIN item_prop ip2
  ON ip2.item_id = i.id AND ip2.row_id=6 AND ip2.value>147811 AND ip2.value<1000000
ORDER BY i.id DESC 
LIMIT 8
```